# Cannot watch a cloned value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is minimal example of my problem. I tried to find a similar question on SO but didn't found anything, so sorry if it's a duplicate.

## App.vue

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <SubComponent v-model="myValue" />
    <SubComponent v-model="myClonedValue" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SubComponent from "./components/SubComponent";

export default {
  components: { SubComponent },
  data: function () {
    return {
      myValue: {
        foo: 45,
        bar: 38,
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    myClonedValue: function () {
      return { ...this.myValue };
    },
  },
  watch: {
    "myValue.foo": function (val, oldVal) {
      console.log(val, oldVal);
    },
    /* This Doesn't work either

    "myClonedValue.foo": function (val, oldVal) {
      console.log(val, oldVal);
    },
    */
    myClonedValue: {
      handler: function (val, oldVal) {
        console.log(val, oldVal);
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

## SubComponent

```
<template>
  <input v-model="value.foo" type="text" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SubComponent",
  props: {
    msg: String,
    value: Object,
  },
};
</script>
```

## Problem

In my main use case, I've a object that I want to modify only if the changes are confirmed. So I clone its values with computed property and for some reason I need to watch if some values have been modified. My problem here, as you can see it online on this CodeSandBox
[CodeSandBox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-grothendieck-r81gt) Is that VueJS doesn't detect any change once I clone the data value. If you change the second input of my example, nothing happens.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: watch: {
        myValue: {
            handler: function(newValue) {
                console.log( newValue.foo)
            },
            deep: true
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computed property doesn't just clone the original value once. It creates a reactive binding and recomputes every time the original value changes. So you need a different approach.

Make clonedValue a regular data property and assign a value to it in created or mounted lifecycle hook. Then you will be able to watch it just as your original value. And what (i assume) is more important, now you will be able to modify the original and cloned values independently.

```
data: {
    myValue: { foo: 1, bar: 2 },
    clonedValue: {}
},
created() {
    this.clonedValue = {...this.myValue}
}
```

Comment: I think it would not work in my main use case because the value I clone is a object taken in a array which is a list. I mean, the user see a lists of element and choose one and can modify it.

Comment: You can create a copy when user selects an element instead of created(). Would this work?

Comment: I think it would work. Could you show me the change I need to do in my minimal example to work ? In my real project I solved my problem in a similare way.

Comment: I think the code i provided above is enough to fix your minimal example. Remove the computed property, add myClonedValue to data and copy myValue into it somewhere (in created for example). Watchers should work fine on both properties.